# Using html and css - will not resize after a certain point

Tags: html, css

This is my Problem : I'm making a website and when I try to resize it the divs that I added (which are empty) stop scaling my whole website after a certain  point.  This is very basic but I'm not sure what's going wrong.

*html-*

```
<body>
    <!-- navbar 01 starts here -->
    <nav class = "navbar navbar-inverse col-lg-12">
        <div class = "container">
            <nav class = "navbar navbar-default">
                <div class = "container-fluid">
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class = "navbar-header">
                        <button class       = "navbar-toggle collapsed"
                                data-target = "#defaultNavbar1"
                                data-toggle = "collapse"
                                type        = "button">
                            <span class = "sr-only">
                                Toggle navigation
                            </span>

                            <span class = "icon-bar">
                            </span>

                            <span class = "icon-bar">
                            </span>

                            <span class = "icon-bar">
                            </span>
                        </button>

                        <a class = "navbar-brand" href = "#">
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div id    = "defaultNavbar1"
                         class = "collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
                            <li>
                                <a href = "#">
                                    Home
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href = "#">
                                    Contact Us
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                        <form class = "navbar-form navbar-left"
                              role  = "search">
                            <div class = "form-group">
                            </div>
                        </form>

                        <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li>
                                <a href = "#">
                                    Support
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href = "#">
                                    Get Started
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
            </nav>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- empty div 1 -->
    <div class = "index-section01">
    </div>

    <!--empty div 2-->
    <div class = "index-section02">
    </div>

    <!--image-half-way-logo to home-->
    <div class = "index-logo01">
        <a href = "index.html">
            <img class  = "img-responsive"
                 alt    = ""
                 src    = "images/3logo_home.png"
                 width  = "1360"
                 height = "138"/>
        </a> 
    </div>

    <!--empty div 3-->
    <div class = "index-section03">
    </div>

    <script src  = "js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"
            type = "text/javascript">
    </script>

    <script src  = "js/bootstrap.js"
            type = "text/javascript">
    </script>
</body>
```

And the css code...

```
body
{
    background-image  : url(images/Final_Web_Home.jpg);
    background-repeat : no-repeat;
    background-size   : cover;
}

.index-section01
{
    min-width      : 100%;
    padding-bottom : 500px;
    padding-right  : 127px;
    padding-top    : 500px;
}

.index-section02
{
    min-width      : 100%;
    padding-bottom : 770px;
    padding-top    : 600px;
}

.index-section03
{
    min-width      : 100%;
    min-width      : 0px;
    padding-bottom : 578px;
    padding-top    : 833px;
}

.index-logo01
{
    display        : block;
    padding-bottom : 85px;
    padding-left   : 132px;
    padding-right  : 0px;
    padding-top    : 224px;
}

.navbar-default
{
    background-color : #FFE016;
    padding-top      : 17px;
} 

.navbar-inverse
{
    background-color : #FFE016;
}
```

This is done on the dreamweaver platform.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you mean by "will not resize."

Comment: There are a lot of divs... We don't have time to try and replicate your error, you have to show us.

Answer (score 0):

You are using bootstrap.

You put all the content inside `<div class="container">`

From [the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container):

> Bootstrap requires a containing element to wrap site contents and house our grid system. You may choose one of two containers to use in your projects. Note that, due to padding and more, neither container is nestable.
>
> Use .container for a responsive **fixed width** container.

So, yes, it stops getting wider when you hit the maximum width of your container. That's the point of that class.

> Use .container-fluid for a full width container, spanning the entire width of your viewport.